# matrix alignment with another matrix row

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

placing a matrix relatively to the 2nd+ row does not seem to work correctly, as if `outer sep` were not set to 0.
I placed a node for x coordinate, and i'd like the new matrix top left corner at same height as second row top right corner of the first matrix. But there's a gap both vertically and horizontally.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix,calc}

\tikzset{
  texttable/.style={row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
                 column sep=-\pgflinewidth,outer sep=0pt,
                      nodes={anchor=center,outer sep=0pt,draw,
                 text width=#1,text depth=.5ex,text height=10pt, font=\large}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix at (0,0) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    matrix anchor=north west,
    texttable={2cm}, align=right] (tb)
    {
    abc & \node (c) {def};\\
    ghi & \node (d) {jkl};\\
    mno & pqr\\
    stu & vwx\\
    };

    \coordinate [label=right:$A$] (ref) at ($(.5\textwidth,0)+(0mm,-3mm)$);
    \fill (ref) circle (1pt);
    \draw [blue] (d.north east) -- ++(60mm,0);
    \draw [blue] (ref) -- ++(0mm,-15mm);
    \matrix at (ref |- d.north east) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    matrix anchor=north west,
    texttable={2cm}, align=right] (tb2)
    {
    ABC & DEF\\
    GHI & JKL\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A quite unpleasant solution would be to shift your matrix anchor: `\matrix at ([xshift=-3.5pt,yshift=3.5pt]ref |- d.north east)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite my comment above, I find not pleasant to cheat with shifting the anchor of the second matrix.

Actually, the matrices have their own `inner sep` that you can set to 0pt. Then, you have to set the `inner sep` for the nodes to a different size.

I think that it should work like this:

[image: matrix alignment]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix,calc}

\tikzset{
  texttable/.style={row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
                 column sep=-\pgflinewidth,outer sep=0pt,
                      nodes={anchor=center,outer sep=0pt,draw,
                 text width=#1,text depth=.5ex,text height=10pt, font=\large}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix at (0,0) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    matrix anchor=north west, nodes={inner sep=3pt},
    texttable={2cm}, align=right] (tb)
    {
    abc & \node (c) {def};\\
    ghi & \node (d) {jkl};\\
    mno & pqr\\
    stu & vwx\\
    };

    \coordinate [label=right:$A$] (ref) at ($(.5\textwidth,0)+(0mm,-3mm)$);
    \fill (ref) circle (1pt);
    \draw [blue] (d.north east) -- ++(60mm,0);
    \draw [blue] (ref) -- ++(0mm,-15mm);
    \matrix at (ref |- d.north east) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    matrix anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt,nodes={inner sep=3pt},
    texttable={2cm}, align=right] (tb2)
    {
    ABC & DEF\\
    GHI & JKL\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### EDIT

It appears that `inner sep=0pt` for the second matrix is not the exact setting. Instead, it's better to use `inner sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth`, so that the lines are exactly coincident, as you can see in the image below:

[image: a better alignment]

Comment: I didn't insert the nodes inner sep into the tikzset definition, but it can be, of course.

Comment: i added `inner sep=0` and `inner sep=3` like this:texttable/.style={row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,nodes={anchor=center,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt,draw,text width=#1,text depth=.5ex,text height=10pt, font=\large}} now it seems fine.

Comment: I think tikz matix has a long way to go. The problem here looks more like a bug. Moreover the setting "text height=xxx" which i'm using here is a trick to get proper vertical alignment of the text across the columns. If i put "minimum height=..." instead, the text will no more be aligned. With "text height=..." i have to adjust it everytime i change the font size.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you try `nicematrix` package, which is very useful and versatile. In the meantime, I think I properly answered to your specific question.

Comment: can you do this with nicematrix here?